# How to reset specific field for all the records in a Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravity, gravityforms

I am trying to reset a specific field in a Gravity Form. Here is an example...

I have a private/administrative field in the form which I need to reset to the number 0 at the end of every week, because I use the entries every week, I just need to reset a specific field every week.

Is there any way I can do that? I know I can loop all the records and modify it, but I am wondering if there is a plugin or something like that that could do this job for me?

Thanks!!

Comment: When you say reset, do you mean that you want to delete all data that was submitted for that field?

Comment: @DavefromGravityWiz Yes, deleting the data of just a specific field, not the whole record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entry Automation add-on by ForGravity can handle deleting a specific field's data automatically:

https://forgravity.com/plugins/entry-automation/

Great developer!

Comment: Which one, tell me more please.

Comment: I linked to the plugin above. When you configure the settings for a given form, you can specify which field should be deleted and when it should happen.